# Cross-domain authentication

Tags: java, http, spring-security, shiro

I'm planning to setup a webservice that will be accessed by other sites. The idea is that the webservice has to be secured, and that each site accessing the web service will be authenticated against their registered domain.

- Site owners will register their domain (like foo.com) from the web front-end of my web service
- Next, their site will issue HTTP methods (`GET, PUT, POST, DELETE`, etc) which will usually be Javascript HTTP Request
- Sites accessing the web service will not need to authenticate; the web service will determine if the domain it is coming from have been registered beforehand, if so I will process the request according to the site's domain.

The problem I am thinking now is whether this kind of system would "scale" and will "work"

I have worked with both Apache Shiro and Spring Security but I have never encountered this kind of requirement.

Comment: Do you want to authenticate according to the client URL?
For example if user access from `http://foo.com` he will get the foo.com user permissions after an authentication, if a user access from `http://example.org` he will the user example.org permissions etc. What scale problem you see here? Also, if user access from `http://subdomain.foo.com` what user should be after the authentication? also foo.com?

Comment: It will scale no worse than using custom tokens, probably better since all the required information would already be in the incoming requests. Wether it will work is a whole other matter though. For one,   the scheme seems heavily geared on Javascript clients. And would be highly prone to spoofed connection information.

Comment: @michael Right that's exactly what I need. As for the "scale" I just used that word to mean, would this idea scale into something feasible.

Comment: @Perception Yes its totally geared towards Javascript clients

Comment: Anyone can suggest an ideal implementation?

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: Url Referral can be always spoofed. This will never be secure as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that by design your system will authenticate users without a password.
It mean, that if use access if user access from http://foo.com he will get the `foo.com` user permissions after an authentication without providing a password.
I want to suggest to solve your problem with your own `PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6167
In your implementation of `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal`, just get the request URL, extract the domain (without subdomain) information from the request URL and authenticate using `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`. 
`AuthenticationUserDetailsService` of `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` should load  registred domains from the database.

Comment: I missed to mention that request will come from a Javascript Ajax call. Thus cross domain

Comment: You can get the idea of what I'm trying to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127369/get-the-origination-host-of-a-javascript-http-request

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a way to do it using custom filter:

1. Add you own [custom filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters), something like PartnerSiteCheckerFilter. It will have a list of IP adresses for each partner server. It will check only API requests (for example /api/**). Any request not matched by IP will be rejected (AccesDeniedException).
2. During registration process save new domain to DB and then get the list of trusted IP addresses

   ```
   InetAddress[] hosts = InetAddress.getAllByName( "www.stackoverflow.com" );
   for(InetAddress host : hosts) {
       String ip = host.getHostAddress();
   } 
   // add ip to a list
   ```
3. Update the list of IPs inside of PartnerSiteCheckerFilter.
4. Prepare some component that will read a list of domains at application startup from DB then get IP for each server and inject this list into PartnerSiteCheckerFilter.
5. The list of trusted servers per domain may be changed at run time. So may be it will be helpfull to provide some way to update it.

Hope this helps. Feel fre to post any questions.

Comment: The problem I face is that, request will not come from a Servlet or any server side HTTP request, rather it will be a Client request, specifically a Javascript HTTP request...