# Get the origination host of a Javascript Http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

When doing a cross domain `HTTP` request from a Javascript client, like JQuery (from a client browser). In the receiving end, will it be able to point out where the Javascript request came from?

Example, I have a site, and it loads up a Javascript that will call a web service, say `foo.com/someapi`

When the API receives the request, what will it be able to get the origination host. Say my site is `bar.com` and when I access `bar.com/index.html` it will load up the page and fire up the javascript HTTP request to `foo.com/someapi`

In the client request there was no server side request involved its pure Javascript.

Furthermore, what if the call is executed from a development environment, like localhost what will be the `hostname` that the receiving `foo.com/someapi` will get?

What does a browser do when doing HTTP request from Javascript:

- In a public domain site
- And with a localhost site

Comment: How are you handling the HTTP request in the server end (foo.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andbdrew mentions the `Origin` header, which is part of the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) specification. It's a useful guide, but not necessarily accurate (or always available).

The only bit of information that is (almost) 100% reliable is the IP address that the request came from (or, rather the IP address of the closest proxy server that relayed the request). That needs to be accurate or else the response will not get back to the computer that made the request. However, it only shows the location of the client, and *not* the origin of the page that is making the request. (And this location will be the same, regardless of whether the page was loaded from file, localhost, or an external site)

With a CORS-supporting browser, what is *supposed* to happen is this:

1. Client requests a page from foo.com
2. foo.com returns a page, including some scripts (possibly as external resources).
3. These scripts run with their origin set to foo.com
4. The scripts try to request another resource from bar.com
5. The client sends a request to bar.com with the HTTP Origin header set to 'foo.com' -- this isn't the client's hostname, but it represents where the scripts came from.
6. bar.com (if it supports CORS) should return the resource with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set (or a related header)

A couple of points:

1. If the client does not support CORS, then it will not send the Origin header at all. See http://caniuse.com/cors for a browser support matrix.
2. If the first request is not to foo.com, but to a `file://` url, then no Origin header will be sent.
3. If that request is not a `file://` url, but instead comes from `localhost`, then the Origin header *should* be set. There's nothing in the spec which says not to, but I haven't checked to see what browsers actually do.
4. There are some other situations in which the Origin header will not be sent; browser extensions and (I believe) Chrome apps will not send it.
5. If the server does not support CORS, then it will ignore the header, and the browser will probably reject the response.

Now, with all of that being said, you can't rely on any of this. CORS is fundamentally a technology designed to help the client browser protect *itself* against the scripts that it runs. It is not about protecting the server, or even letting the server know who is accessing the data, since it could be very easily faked. The reason it exists is to give "good" scripts running in a "good" browser a way of saying who they are -- a way that "bad" scripts running in the same "good' browser should not be able to impersonate.

It absolutely does not mean that the server which actually controls the resource should rely on that header for any sort of security. If the data being accessed is really important, there should be proper access controls on it (https, passwords, and secure cookie-based sessions are a good combination)

Comment: Ok I see, anyway, just to add reason I am trying to do this is that I was thinking of a really basic way for a website to be able to do a POST on a web service (external/other domain), when I click say a submit button on the website. While the webservice can identify where the request came from.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is `bar.com`, the `ORIGIN` header will be set to `bar.com`.

You can check this out in the NET tab of your browser's inspector.

EDIT: If you are coming from your dev environment or localhost, you should set up your host file (assuming linux / mac) and alias local.bar.com to 127.0.0.1. Then, the `ORIGIN` header will be set to local.bar.com.

This header should not be mistaken for an authentication strategy. To try and limit access to authorized users, you could look into OAuth at http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: What if it came from a dev environment, a localhost environment, then I fire a HTTP request to foo.com/someapi?

Comment: The Origin header is part of CORS, not the HTTP spec. It should be set by the browser if it supports CORS, and if the origin is not a local file URL, but you can't necessarily count on it.

Comment: @IanClelland So this can easily be faked

Comment: Yes. Don't trust it for any meaningful security.

Comment: @IanClelland If `ORIGIN` is not set, the browser doesn't support CORS, and the request will not be sent so you don't have to worry about it :). In these cases, you will need to fall back on other technologies, like JSONP or using a proxy of some sort.

Comment: @Andbdrew I mean that the *server* shouldn't trust it for anything. If a request is received, it could mean that a modern, uncompromised browser sent it, or it could mean that an older browser was used, or a proxy, or some other piece of software, or me, typing HTTP over telnet. The script running in the browser is generally fine to trust the browser's handling of security issues.

Comment: @IanClelland agreed. The `ORIGIN` header is not an authentication strategy. You can and should use something OAuth, and then only attach CORS headers if the request is correctly authenticated.

Comment: @Andbdrew Yes, I know about Oauth, however I was thinking of a really basic way for a website to be able to do a POST on a web service, when I click say a submit button on the website. While the webservice can identify where the request came from.

Comment: @xkm then you are looking for the `ORIGIN` header :)